El InputNumber de PrimeReact no toma mas width
Hola buenas a todos alguein sabra por que este componente  no toma ningun tipo de width ya lo intente con tailwind y con el style pero no toma ningun tipo de with es el unico componente que no me esta respetando los estilos
<div className="card flex flex-wrap gap-3 p-fluid">
                    <div className="flex-auto">
                        <label htmlFor="numTables">Número</label>
                        <div className="w-full">
                            <InputNumber
                                value={numTables}
                                onChange={(e) => setNumTables(e.value)}
                                min={1}
                                className="w-full"
                                style={{ width: "100% !important" }}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <small
                            id="miInput-help"
                            className="p-d-block p-mt-2 p-text-muted"
                        >
                            Lorem
                        </small>
                    </div>
                </div>


No uso PrimeReact ¿Pero estas seguro de que se puede usar el className en tu componente? En la API no aparece ese atributo, pero aparece otro llamado InputClassName.
https://primereact.org/inputnumber/#api.InputNumber.props.inputClassName
Si eso no funciona tendrías que ver los componentes padre para ver si en efecto tienen un width definido
